# Display Doughnut Pie Chart As Circle Progress Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to ask if there is a way to make  Pie Chart As Circle Progress with percent value, I want just one slice colored 
something like this:

[image]

This is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htw0tw55/) for now I want just one data.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="chartProgress" width="300px" height="200"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var chartProgress = document.getElementById("chartProgress");
if (chartProgress) {
var myChartCircle = new Chart(chartProgress, {
type: 'doughnut',
data: {
  labels: ["Africa", 'null'],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Population (millions)",
    backgroundColor: ["#5283ff"],
    data: [68, 48]
  }]
},
plugins: [{
  beforeDraw: function(chart) {
    var width = chart.chart.width,
        height = chart.chart.height,
        ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

    ctx.restore();
    var fontSize = (height / 150).toFixed(2);
    ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#9b9b9b";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

    var text = "68%",
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = height / 2;

    ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
    ctx.save();
  }
}],
options: {
  legend: {
    display: false,
  },
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  cutoutPercentage: 85
}
});
}
```

I know I can do it with normal HTML&CSS or using simple plugin but I want to do it using Chart.js

Comment: off the top of my head, you could probably get the required effect by putting a dummy value (like 68 - 32). But it may be difficult to get the text in the middle without some custom code or customisation

Comment: What amazing approach. I never thinked before use ChartJS to create a Circular Progressbar. It comes already with animation and no problems about the size of the canvas, it will be rendered correctly.

Answer (score 13):

The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. You already use the `beforeDraw` hook to draw text in the middle of the doughnut.

You could now also use the `beforeInit` hook to modify the chart configuration in order to fit your needs:

```
beforeInit: (chart) => {
  const dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
  chart.data.labels = [dataset.label];
  dataset.data = [dataset.percent, 100 - dataset.percent];
}
```

Given this code, the definition of your `dataset` would look simple as follows:

```
{
  label: 'Africa / Population (millions)',
  percent: 68,
  backgroundColor: ['#5283ff']
}
```

Last you have to define a [`tooltips.filter`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#filter-callback), so that the tooltip appears only at the relevant segment.

```
tooltips: {
  filter: tooltipItem => tooltipItem.index == 0
}
```

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
var myChartCircle = new Chart('chartProgress', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Africa / Population (millions)',
      percent: 68,
      backgroundColor: ['#5283ff']
    }]
  },
  plugins: [{
      beforeInit: (chart) => {
        const dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
        chart.data.labels = [dataset.label];
        dataset.data = [dataset.percent, 100 - dataset.percent];
      }
    },
    {
      beforeDraw: (chart) => {
        var width = chart.chart.width,
          height = chart.chart.height,
          ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
        ctx.restore();
        var fontSize = (height / 150).toFixed(2);
        ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#9b9b9b";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        var text = chart.data.datasets[0].percent + "%",
          textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
          textY = height / 2;
        ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
        ctx.save();
      }
    }
  ],
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    cutoutPercentage: 85,
    rotation: Math.PI / 2,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    tooltips: {
      filter: tooltipItem => tooltipItem.index == 0
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartProgress"></canvas>
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as Correct. It's amazing!