# How to I fix RTL issue for chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm working on a **project status chart**. It's working well for `LTR direction`. But in `RTL direction` it's not working well. Actually problem with the canvas text. I want to show the text in the chart middle for `RTL and LTR both direction`.

I want like this: https://ibb.co/7YCr9L7

I can't fix the text direction.

**Here is my code:**

```js
var projectProgressChart = document.getElementById("chartProgress");

        new Chart(projectProgressChart, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                        label: 'Complete',
                        percent: 20,
                        backgroundColor: ['#6690F4'],
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }]
            },
            plugins: [{
                    beforeInit: (chart) => {
                        const dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
                        chart.data.labels = [dataset.label];
                        dataset.data = [dataset.percent, 100 - dataset.percent];
                    }
                },
                {
                    beforeDraw: (chart) => {
                        var width = chart.chart.width,
                                height = chart.chart.height,
                                ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
                        ctx.restore();
                        ctx.font = 1.5 + "em sans-serif";
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#9b9b9b";
                        ctx.textBaseline = "center";
                        var text = chart.data.datasets[0].percent + "%",
                                textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
                                textY = height / 2;
                        ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
                        ctx.save();
                    }
                }
            ],
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                cutoutPercentage: 90,
                rotation: Math.PI / 2,
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                tooltips: {
                    filter: tooltipItem => tooltipItem.index === 0,
                    callbacks: {
                        afterLabel: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                            var dataset = data['datasets'][0];
                            var percent = Math.round((dataset['data'][tooltipItem['index']] / dataset["_meta"][Object.keys(dataset["_meta"])[0]]['total']) * 100);
                            return '(' + percent + '%)';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="chartProgress" width="300px" height="200"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please someone help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the `rtl` option on Legend in the documentation? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv If I use `RTL` option then it's working same. No change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63223641/2358409

Comment: @uminder No. There've the same issue. That's not working on rtl. The text shown in wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the calculation of `textX` is not correct.

EDIT: codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/vYjJbKp

Try with:

```
textX = width - Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
```